# Call Function with Delay When Textbox Changes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can't seem to google up an example of how this is done.

I have successfully created a textbox that calls a function every time it changes.  What I would like to do is only call the function when the user has stopped typing for x milliseconds.

I know how to do it in JQuery using the keyup event, and can probably make it work this way, but want to do it "the Angular Way".

**Edit**

Maybe it wasn't clear from the tag or text, but I am using AngularJS, and want to use correct methodology for that framework to create this delay functionality.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For angular approach can inject `$timeout` in controller as dependency and use `$watch` on scope variable you've assigned in `ng-model`.

```
var timer=false;
$scope.ModelName='foo';
$scope.$watch('ModelName', function(){
  if(timer){
      $timeout.cancel(timer)
  }  
  timer= $timeout(function(){
      /* run code*/
   },delay)
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I already had the watch bit and was injecting $timeout into my controller (but had no idea how to use it), so that fixed it in 30 seconds flat.

Comment: `$timeout` returns a promise... I had to look that part up in docs to figure out how to use `cancel()`.

Comment: What happens if you dont cancel? Because its setTimeout not setInterval?

Comment: @Vury certainly need to cancel promise but not sure if `timer=$timeout(...` wouldn't do automatic cancel or not. Docs do say that cancel will trigger promise reject

Comment: I suggest to initialize the timer var to null instead of false. My IDE throws a warning with a boolean.

Answer (score 28):

There is `ng-model-options` for this manner

```
<input id="delayedModel" ng-model="delayedModel" ng-change="callDelayed()" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }" />
```

the `callDelayed` method only calls after 500 ms from typing the last char or on blur

Here is the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: Help me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Solved it in an instant. Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

While @charlietfl provided totally acceptable answer I would like to share with you another approach without using `$watch` method:

**Template:**

```
<input id="delayedModel" ng-model="delayedModel" ng-change="callDelayed()"/>
```

**Controller:**

```
    (function (timer, delay) {
        $scope.callDelayed= function () {
            if(timer){
                $timeout.cancel(timer)
            }
            timer = $timeout(function(){

                /* run code*/

            }, delay)
        };
    })(false, 500);
```

Maybe it's worth to point out why self-executing anonymous function is used. The main reason is to not pollute controller scope with `time` and `delay` variables. In this case they are defined in local function scope.

**[UPDATE]**

I've also found an interesting AngularJS project called [angular-debounce](https://github.com/shahata/angular-debounce) that makes it really easy to achieve same effect. Using `debounce` directive it's possible to dealy model update like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="delayedModel" debounce="500"></input>
```